# Numba with datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, numba

Is it possible to speed up the following function using Numba?

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def loanDates(startDate, endDate, freq):
    startDate=pd.to_datetime(startDate)
    endDate=pd.to_datetime(endDate)
    if int(12/freq)==12/freq:

        FirstDate=pd.to_datetime(dt.datetime(startDate.year,startDate.month,1))

        ts=pd.date_range(start=FirstDate,end=endDate,freq=str(-int(12/freq))+"MS")
        ts=list(ts)
        for i in range(len(ts)):
            if startDate.day>ts[i].days_in_month:
                ts[i]=ts[i]+pd.DateOffset(days=ts[i].days_in_month-1)
            else:
                ts[i]=ts[i]+pd.DateOffset(days=startDate.day-1)
        ts=pd.DatetimeIndex(ts)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'str': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'type'>

File "<ipython-input-58-3eac94417232>", line 16:
def loanDates(startDate, endDate, freq):
    <source elided>

        ts=pd.date_range(start=FirstDate,end=endDate,freq=str(-int(12/freq))+"MS")
```

So as I understand there is a problem with datetime and Numba. I tried using instead of pd.date_range method numpy arange but it didnt work out for what I need:

```
x=np.arange(np.datetime64(sd), np.datetime64(ed),str(-int(12/fq))+"MS")
```

Gives error

```
ValueError: Could not convert object to NumPy timedelta
```

So are there any possibilities to use numba for this kind of function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slow part is your `for` loop, and you don't need Numba to optimize it.  Instead of this:

```
    ts=list(ts)
    for i in range(len(ts)):
        if startDate.day>ts[i].days_in_month:
            ts[i]=ts[i]+pd.DateOffset(days=ts[i].days_in_month-1)
        else:
            ts[i]=ts[i]+pd.DateOffset(days=startDate.day-1)
```

Do it vectorized, something like this:

```
    overflow = startDate.day > ts.days_in_month # array of bools
    offsets = (ts.days_in_month-1).where(overflow, startDate.day-1)
    ts += pd.DateOffset(days=offsets)
```

Or simplify further:

```
    offsets = np.minimum(ts.days_in_month, startDate.day) - 1
    ts += pd.DateOffset(days=offsets)
```

This should be at least 10x faster.

Comment: It makes sense however pd.DateOffset seems to be accepting only ints/floats as offsets variable. I'm getting the following error: `TypeError: Invalid type <class 'pandas.core.indexes.numeric.Int64Index'>. Must be int or float.` So it kinda requires me to use loop.

Comment: What version of Pandas are you using?  Does this work for you: `pd.DateOffset(days=pd.Int64Index([1,2,3]))`?  It works in 0.23 for sure.  Also try using `DateOffset(days=offsets.values)` and see if that works.

Comment: First thing works for me. However `DateOffset(days=offsets.values)` does not work.Im using pandas 0.24.2

Comment: You may want to reproduce it with following data: `sd = "2022-12-31 00:00:00"
ed = "2019-03-31 00:00:00"
fq = 12` `loanDates(sd, ed, fq)`

Comment: In that case `ts` is empty which is why it doesn't work.  Try a case with non-empty data.  You can add an explicit check like `if ts.empty: return` to handle the degenerate case.

Comment: What do you mean by empty? I'm getting corect `DatetimeIndex` object for `ts` variable.

Comment: `DatetimeIndex(['2022-12-01', '2022-11-01', '2022-10-01', '2022-09-01',
               '2022-08-01', '2022-07-01'...`

Comment: Maybe you can sort of work through the code I gave you and try to debug it.  I'm not going to debug it all for you.  I think the basic ideas are all there.

Comment: Okay, thanks anyway. I'll try it out, however my guess is that this idea(to rewrite the loop) is not really applicable to my problem. I think I need to rewrite other parts of the function as well.